# How to refresh cache from DB in django rest service?

Tags: python, django, multithreading

The main intent of this question is to know how to refresh cache from db (which is populated by some other team not in our control) in django rest service which will then be used in serving requests received on rest end point.
Currently I am using the following approach but my concern is since python (cpython with GIL) is not multithreaded then can we have following type of code in rest service where one thread is populating cache every 30 mins and main thread is serving requests on rest end point.Here is sample code only for illustration.

```
# mainproject.__init__.py
globaldict = {} # cache
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(1800):            
            refershcachefromdb()  # function that takes around 5-6 mins for refreshing cache (global datastructure) from db


refershcachefromdb() # this is explicitly called to initially populate cache
thread = MyThread(stop_flag)
thread.start() # started thread that will refresh cache every 30 mins



# views.py
import mainproject
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_data(request):    
    str_param = request.GET.get('paramid')
    if str_param:
        try:
            paramids = [int(x) for x in str_param.split(",")]
        except ValueError:
            return JsonResponse({'Error': 'This rest end point only accept comma seperated integers'}, status=422)
        # using global cache to get records
        output_dct_lst = [mainproject.globaldict[paramid] for paramid in paramids if paramid in mainproject.globaldict]
        if not output_dct_lst:
            return JsonResponse({'Error': 'Data not available'}, status=422)
        else:
            return JsonResponse(output_dct_lst, status=200, safe=False)
```

Comment: Before looking at this closely, are you aware that [Django has built-in caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/)?

Comment: How is this different from any other cache expiry issue?

Comment: @Chris I mainly want to know where i should initialize cache and how i can refresh cache and serve request in parallel ?

Comment: Have you read about Django's built-in cache like I suggested? There's lots of good info there.